# Selenium Webdriver, Python - capture text from browser and store in a variable?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automated browser testing for my company, and I want to be able to capture text from the browser and add it to a string (such as an order number).  How would I do that?  I know how to find the element containing the text, but how do I store it to use later?  Thanks greatly!  (I'm using Python 2.7).

Answer (score 0):

assign the text to a variable and use it later.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://foo.com')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('foo')
txt = elem.text  # now the element text is stored in the "txt" variable
```

Comment: My knowledge of python is outrageously limited - can you tell me what you're doing in the 4th line?  in the third line you're finding what's in the element, why do you need the 4th one?  does that convert anything that's not text into text?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work.  I get `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'txt'`.Is there a module I need to import that I'm missing?  Also, when i print `elem`, I get `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x101990510>`.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: try `txt = elem.text` in the 4th line. The 3rd line gets the element identified by the id `foo`, and the 4th get's its text and assigns it to the variable `txt`, which you can use later.